# Method for determining convergence of sinus/cosinus series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

What's the method used for testing convergence of these type of series?
$$
\sum_{n = 2}^\infty\sin\frac{(n^2-1)\pi}{n}
$$

Answer (score 1):

You have

$$\sin\left(\frac{(n^2-1)\pi}{n}\right) = \sin\left(n\pi -\frac{\pi}{n}\right) $$

$$=\sin(n\pi)\cos(\pi/n) - \cos(n\pi)\sin(\pi/n)$$

$$= 0 +(-1)^{n+1}\sin(\pi/n).$$

So on one hand you have an alternating series and on the other hand you have something asymptotic to the harmonic series.

Comment: Note that the convergence follows by the Leibniz criterion. :-)